# how to set position of cursor in bottom right of textarea in textfield in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I need text area cursor starting point will be bottom right
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsS8O.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can set the TextField property textAlign at end,Hope this will work for you, Thanks

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: SafeArea(
                child: Center(
                    child: Container(
                        width: 290,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: TextField(
                            autocorrect: true,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                            )))))));
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
textarea {
    text-align: right;
}
```